# Выбор последней записи в которой сумма была >0

Tags: база-данных, запрос, firebird

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно сделать выборку.
Не могу выбрать последнего поставщика, выбираются все что были. Как это можно исправить? Условие max не подходит так как номер поставщика будет не по возрастанию, а по условию sum>0. Сумма больше 0 могла быть в промежутке с 1-9 месяц включительно.

`select trader.name
from trader, monthly_accounting mm, daily_accounting dd
where mm.trader=trader.i and mm.sum>0 and mm.m<=dd.m and mm.y=dd.y and dd.y=2019 and dd.m=9 and dd.d=10 and dd.post=102358`

Comment: покажите структуры таблиц. Каков критерий "последнего" - максимум даты?

Comment: Критерий последнего и дата максимум - это сумма>0, то есть в каком месяце и на какого поставщика поставили сумму того поставщика и должно выбрать, если последняя сумма была в феврале тогда нужно выбрать поставщика в феврале и т.д.

Comment: выбирайте по sum>0, сортируйте по дате по убыванию и берите первую `limit=1`. Как сортировать, без структуры данных не подскажу

Comment: Скрины наверное не смогу сделать,  только описание написать на структуру

Comment: Таблица trader ( trader.i, trader.name). Таблица monthly_accounting ( monthly_accounting.m (месяц), monthly_accounting.y (год), monthly_accounting.firm (номер фирмы), monthly_accounting.trader (номер поставщика), monthly_accounting.sum(месячная сумма))  Таблица daily_accounting (daily_accounting.m (месяц), daily_accounting.y (год), daily_accounting.firm (номер фирмы), daily_accounting.sum (сумма за один день))

Comment: Надеюсь не сильно запутанно вышло

Comment: monthly_accounting.firm (номер фирмы)=daily_accounting.firm (номер фирмы)

Comment: trader.i=monthly_accounting.trader

Comment: перенесите это в се в вопрос

Answer (score 2):

```
select **first 1** trader.name
from 
     trader, 
     monthly_accounting mm, 
     daily_accounting dd
where 
     mm.trader=trader.i 
     and mm.sum>0 
     and mm.m<=dd.m 
     and mm.y=dd.y 
     and dd.y=2019 
     and dd.m=9 
     and dd.d=10 
     and dd.post=102358
**order by trader.name desc**
```

Comment: top1 для firebird не подходит

Comment: попробуйте: вместо top1   FIRST 1

Comment: Пробовали не сработало